# How to filter Graph Api friends_location that are not empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm experimenting with the new Facebook project template for MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2013. I've added a Location property to the `MyAppUserFriend` class to get the location of each friend. I need to filter the location results for friends who have a location. In other words, I don't want to return friends with an empty location field.

Below is the method that gets the `MyAppUser` and `MyAppUserFriend` results.

```
    [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos", "friends_location")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();

            return View(user);
        }

        return View("Error");
    }
```

Here is the class for MyAppUserFriend. It's my understanding that I can filter the results using the FacebookFieldModifier attribute, but I can't find what field modifiers are available except `search?type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000`

```
public class MyAppUserFriend
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }    
    public FacebookLocation Location { get; set; }

    public double Distance { get; set; }

    [FacebookFieldModifier("height(100).width(100)")] // This sets the picture height and width to 100px.
    public FacebookConnection<FacebookPicture> Picture { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**:

I experimented with FQL statements and was unable to filter the results for location because the **'current_location'** field is not indexable and therefore cannot be used in the **WHERE** clause.

I also looked into searches the search queries but these are limited public objects only and it doesn't appear that search queries can be combined with the location parameters and/or FQL statements.

Regarding the The field modifiers, they are available on the location object are limited to 'limit' and 'uid' only, so I was not able to user field modifiers to limit the results the way I needed. I was able to find the field modifiers in the graph explorer in case anyone comes across this question in the future.

[image]